# Cannot make predictions after recursive feature elimination

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have carried out recursive feature elimination on my dataset and now trying to make predictions based on the features that are returned by my RFE but keep encountering this error:

```
ValueError: X has 31 features per sample; expecting 9
```

This is the code I have written to get the optimal features and transform my data based on the features returned

```
no_list = np.arange(1,len(list(dat)))
acc_score = 0
n_features = 0
score_list = []
for x in range(len(no_list)):
    X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size = 0.2,random_state=100)
    log_reg = LogisticRegression()
    rfe = RFE(log_reg,no_list[x])
    X_train_rfe = rfe.fit_transform(X_train,y_train)
    X_test_rfe = rfe.transform(X_test)
    log_reg.fit(X_train_rfe,y_train)
    score = log_reg.score(X_test_rfe,y_test)
    score_list.append(score)
    if(score > acc_score):
        acc_score = score
        n_features = no_list[x]
rfe = RFE(log_reg,n_features)
rfe.fit_transform(X_train,y_train)
predictions = rfe.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: It appears that the model `log_reg` was trained on subset of 9 features. Then at the end the n_features is larger than the pruned data that you fit the model with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transform your `X_test` before sending it into predict. Your `rfe` uses the `log_reg` model that only take `n_features`.

```
rfe = RFE(log_reg,n_features)
rfe.fit_transform(X_train,y_train)
X_test = rfe.transform(X_test)
predictions = rfe.predict(X_test)
```